# Videos of Youtube Not Working On Cordova Android App

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, iframe, video

I am trying to build a video application in cordova for Android Platform in that i had completed to display video from youtube embed url .And it is working fine for some video but some video facing issue as given below in screen shots.

[image]

For playing youtube video in in-line i used all the basic configuration like

```
1>For AndroidManifest.xml 

    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

2>For config.xml
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" /> 
    <access origin="http://*.youtube.com" />
```

**And the iframe for playing in-line video is given below**

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html"  width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8Q2YA5_sOZY?html5=1" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

Comment: the video is probably encoded in a format that html5 can't play, only flash or an app...

Comment: but when it tried to play it on my web application it is working

Comment: then it sounds like the videos are defective by design for external embeds...

Comment: dandavis@ thanks for reply please if you have any suggession regarding that how to get it works on mobile app please help me out i tried for some video plug-in but they use to play that video on youtube player but i want to play it on inline iframe not on youtube player

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about circumventing copyright restrictions.

Comment: but youtube has provided us the embedeb code for it please check this  link https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=8Q2YA5_sOZY in embed section youtube is providing embed iframe tag as <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8Q2YA5_sOZY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: @323go can you please give me some detail explanation on it because i am not familiar with it

Comment: @323go no i don't think so it is regarding copyright issue because it is working fine in my web application without this issue

Comment: The video you're trying to play is restricted from playing in embedded sites, like your app. It's likely because the copyright holder will want to monetize the video for mobile use. You are asking how to circumvent this restriction.

Comment: @323go ohh thanks for this information but is there any hack to get it work on android cordova mobile app

Comment: try these two Video plugins: https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer  and https://github.com/remcob00/cordova-phonegap_youtube_player_api_android

Comment: @Ricky, your "hack" would be circumventing a playback restriction and at the very least violate Youtube's terms of service, at most, be illegal. You can't ask for help with that here.

Comment: @AAhad ya shure i tried it but the problem is that it is opening youtube video of my app in youtubes official android app but i don't want to do so i want to play it in my app itself

Comment: @323go ok but is there any plugin so that it may help me to play it in-line in my app itself without prompting me to play it in youtube app

Comment: There might be other plugins as well, search them. Also see this https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: @AAhad thanks i will try for it .

Comment: @AAhad no success for  developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference on mobile device same issue here also .

Comment: When it is able to run the same Video in a native App it means there is NO restriction of opening video on a mobile device. There must be something else. If have not already tried, check it in pure native code and if it works fine then it means ONLY hybrid app has issues and there is nothing from youtube or copyrights. So in this way Webview layer will have some issues , or some HTTP protocol or encoding etc.

Comment: @AAhad thanks i will find out way to overcome this restriction .

Comment: If it turns out to be Hybrid ONLY restriction then let me know. I too like to give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @Ricky
Any solution to this yet?

Answer (score -1):

It's not about your code, it's about country restrictions and youtube policy.